# Herkunft von »mitgenommen aussehen«

Tags: etymology

> Kurt **sieht** ziemlich **mitgenommen aus**. Er ist wohl direkt von einer langen Nacht ins Büro gekommen.

Die Bedeutung ist klar:

> Kurt sieht nicht aus, als wäre er in bester Verfassung bzw. in Bestform.

Kann auch auf Gegenstände angewendet werden:

> Diese Hose kannst du nicht mehr anziehen, so **mitgenommen** wie sie schon **aussieht**. Wirf sie weg!

Bedeutet:

> Die Hose ist verschlissen, lädiert, beschädigt, ausgebleicht o.ä.

Meine Frage:

Wie kommt das Wort »mitgenommen« in dieser Fügung? Woher stammt die Redewendung »mitgenommen aussehen«?

Comment: "Bist du per Anhalter gekommen?" - "Nein, wieso?" - "Na, du siehst so mitgenommen aus"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [mitnehmen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GM05898#XGM05898)

Eine im Verb nur noch zum Teil vorhandene Bedeutung von *mitnehmen* ist folgende:

> **mitnehmen** *gewaltsam, beschädigen, übel behandeln, wie erobertes, an sich gerissenes;* [...] später ist die kurze fassung gewöhnlich: mitnehmen, *für verwüsten, arm machen, exhaurire [...] mitnehmen, als die Krankheit einen Menschen [...]* <sup>[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GM05898#XGM05898)</sup>

Man erkennt diese Bedeutung noch in folgenden Beispielen:

> Die Hitze nimmt mich ganz schön mit.
> Von den Anstrengungen sah er ganz mitgenommen aus.